# Why does excel not sort these dates properly?

Tags: excel

See the attached pictures. The cells are formated as dates. They are formulas with =IF(ISERROR(..),..,..).

[image]

Comment: What's the rest of the formula?

Comment: some of your "dates" appear to be text that look like dates and others are true dates.

Comment: So the first column is a SUBSTITUTE on a webrequest, the 2nd column is a manual over-ride and the 3rd column combines them taking the first if non error. 

Do I need to actively CAST these things to dates instead of just select and format as dates? I don't get why excel makes this so weird.

Comment: Notice how content in some cells is right aligned while others are left aligned? The right-aligned cells have date values, while the left-aligned cells have text values.

Comment: Cell formatting is just a mask of the numbers, if it is a string it gets skipped.  SUBSTITUTE return a string.  Most likely one only needs to preface the SUBSTITUTE with `--` to change to a true date:  `=--SUBSTITUTE(...`

Comment: @ScottCraner What kind of sorcery is this? `--` did it. NEver heard of this before. Thanks.

Comment: `--` is the double unary. More detail [here](https://exceljet.net/glossary/double-unary).